# How to set .qss Style Sheet dynamically to my App

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I would like to apply a .qss Style Sheet to my application dynamically : there would be an option in my toolbar to select the .qss file to apply directly, .qss files already exist, and load, without closing the App, the new style.
I don't know how to manage it since :

- there is no setStyleSheet in QMainWindow
- it seems there is no good way to get the QApplication instance from QMainWindow (by the way, is it so silly to conceive : access of app instance from mainWindow ? it is an innocent question)

So I have this code, I don't know where to put :

```
if( !QFile::exists(fileName) )
    return;
QFile styleFile(fileName);
if( !styleFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    return;
QString style( styleFile.readAll() );
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [`qApp`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#qApp)?

Answer (score 1):

As G.M. said in a comment, qApp is the answer (a global pointer referring to the unique application object).

Comment: Please consider asking the commenter to post the comment as an answer and accept/upvote it, instead of posting it yourself. People, who had provided useful help deserve to get credited for that.